# Limit the number of items in an array

Tags: php

I have an array that gets processed through a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($images as $imageChoices) {
    Do stuff here
}
```

How do I limit the loop to only process the first 4 items in the array?

Comment: don't use `foreach`, use `for`. `For-Each`, can you see it there? No limitation, runs for each item in array

Comment: `for` (when incrementing an integer for the keys) only works with `$i`-based, incrementally increasing array keys. The OP doesn't specify whether that's the case or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) function can be used.

```
foreach(array_slice($images, 0, 4) as $imageChoices) { … }
```

This enables you to only loop over the values that you want, without keeping count of how many you have done so far.

Comment: NB array_slice has an additional parameter to preserve keys.

Comment: Thanks @symcbean, though that parameter would be useless in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You basically count each iteration with the `$i` and stop the loop with `break` when 4 is reached...

```
$i = 0;
foreach($images as $imageChoices) {
    //Do stuff here
    $i++;
    if($i >= 4 { break; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($images) && $i<4; $i++) {
  // Use $images[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter variable and increase it's count on each loop.

Apply check according to  counter value

something like below:

```
 $count=1;

  foreach($images as $imageChoices) {
   if($count <=4)
   {
        Do stuff here
   } 
   else
   {
       Jump outside of loop  break;
   }
    $count++;

  }
```

OR you can do same with `for loop` instead of `foreach` and also with some inbuilt PHP `Array` functions

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
  // Use $images[$i]
}
```

Comment: the for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {} method pre-supposes that the array elements are numbered 0,1,2,3...

Answer (score 0):

```php
function process()
{
  //Some stuff
}

process(current($imageChoices));
process(next($imageChoices));
process(next($imageChoices));
process(next($imageChoices));
```